# Odata connected service avoid storing to list

Tags: c#, list, object, odata, microsoft-dynamics

I am currenlty trying to extract certain that is publicly available using OdataQueryServices. 
The service is currently publishing products, and I am able to extract certain product objects out by first storing the whole product list to a list. 
This is not wanted, due to space consumption, and not being able to retrieve the latest info, as this information will be changing.

I am able to this

```
        ODataQueryService ax = new ODataQueryService(new Uri(config.conf));
        ax.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        var stock = new List<Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.ODataQuery.InventTable>();


        try
        {
            stock = ax.InventTable.ToList();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.ODataQuery.InventTable price = stock.Find(x => x.InventTable_ItemId == "030001");
```

but as mentioned, this stores information locally.

I would to do something like this:

```
        try
        {
            var item = ax.InventTable.Where(o => o.InventTable_ItemId == "030001");
            Console.WriteLine(item.Expression);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Does the service have documentation? If they expose OData then most likely they support OData filters.

Comment: `DataserviceQuery` does not have the option to `.AddQueryOption`.

Comment: Max protocolversion V2

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library but even if it doesn't you could resort to HTTP calls instead of using the .net client.

Comment: You might want to tag your question with MS Dynamics. I just now noticed that was your client. Did you see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/fin-and-ops/get-started/advanced-filtering-query-options) ?

Comment: it does not give me a proper output, the output is an error...?